# c++ useless-cast from size_t to uint32_t for different targets

Tags: c++, gcc, static-cast

I have some code that builds for different targets. It also has some legacy functions that take uint32_t instead of size_t - which is annoying when I want to cast size_t types to it - with the levels of warnings that we have set (lots of gcc warnings).

So here is a contrived example:

```
val32 = static_cast<uint32_t>(strings.size());
val64 = static_cast<uint64_t>(strings.size());  // ERROR
```

Depending on which arch this runs on, one of the two lines above will complain with useless cast warning (which we treat as errors). Now I know there are some ways around this like, change the code to take size_t... but, that is not my question. My question is, when this situation arises, how can I best tackle this.

I have come up with a solution - but it requires reference passing of variables:

```cpp
template<typename TO, typename FROM>
TO static_cast_if_different(const FROM &value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<TO, FROM>)
        return value;
    else
        return static_cast<TO>(value);
}
```

Now this works, but I feel there is a better way (perhaps built in to the standard - or an improvement of what I have done here)?

See the full example code  here: https://godbolt.org/z/87hao1aTb

full list of warning flags for gcc: `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wunreachable-code -Wlogical-op -Wshadow -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wparentheses -Wmisleading-indentation -Werror -Wno-psabi -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wuseless-cast -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference`

Note: I don't want to remove the useless-cast warning flag as that is useful else where

Comment: It's a good solution *and* you can add an assertion that no meaningful bits are thrown away.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. sorry - I did not understand that assertion part, can you explain slightly more?

Comment: also - general question - if this is the solution, is it better to pass by ref or value here? - I think ref, incase the types are large...but...

Comment: You probably want to just handle integral types, no?

Comment: You can add `static_cast<TO>(value)==value`. By the way you don't even need the cast or `if (std::is_same_v...)`, `TO result = value;` will work just the same (in case of unsigned types). By const ref or by value doesn't matter, it will be inlined and completely optimized away anyway.

Comment: I mean, `assert(static_cast<TO>(value)==value)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes *probably*, good point! - maybe I can add that as an extra caveat to the template - or if I need more I can then do a ref only version for non intagral types (if needed)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.ah thanks - I was really stumped by your first comment!.. gave up and moved to your updated comment and now it makes sense :)    feel free to add as a complete answer, I think it has value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good solution, and it can still be improved somewhat.

1. The cast and the `std::is_same_v` are not really necessary. A simple assignment will do exactly the same thing (when working with `unsigned` integral types, but we want to check for that). The function could look like this:

   ```
    template<typename TO, typename FROM>
    TO legacy_size_cast(FROM value)
    {
       static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<FROM> && std::is_unsigned_v<TO>,
                     "Only unsigned types can be cast here!");
       TO result = value;
       return result;
    }
   ```

   You will still have a visual indication of a type conversion at the call site, which I suppose is what you're after. But if you do need an actual cast for some reason, you can still add it:

   ```
    TO result = static_cast<TO>(value);
   ```
2. You can protect against accidental overflow by adding this:

   ```
    assert(result == value);
   ```

   This might not look like something terribly useful (who is going to allocate a single 4GB object?) but actually it can catch nasty bugs when you pass a negative offset, e.g. `(uint64_t)(-1)`.  This is actually a huge positive value, but it behaves like a `-1` in arithmetic... until you convert it to `uint32_t` and then back to `uint64_t`, then it suddenly doesn't, and the `assert` will catch that.
3. It does not matter if you pass by reference or by value. In a release build, the function is going to be inlined and optimized away completely anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using macros.
E.g.

```
#ifdef SOME_ARCH
code
#else
other code
#endif
```

Then when you compile for some_arch, add `-D SOME_ARCH` to the compile flags.